# Best/Good tool for monitoring a server, with web interface?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring

I'm pretty new to Linux and I'm looking for a monitoring tool that has a web front end. Specifically looking for stats on the following:

- Storage space, Used/Free
- CPU Activity
- CPU Temps
- RAM Usage

Everything I would expect from server monitoring software, having the ability to send emails based on things like high CPU temps would be a bonus.

Ideally I'd like to find something free & open source but will pay if something is worth it.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin#monitoring

Answer (score 5):

I like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) - pretty much with just installation (munin-node on each host and munin "master" on the collecting and graphing server), and pointing to the hosts, I got full detail on hardware sensors, cpu, disks, memory, interrupts, lots more. It has a web interface for viewing but not as far as I know for configuring.

[Cacti](http://cacti.net/) is a well-established monitoring tool with a full web ui for configuration and management. It is good at ping and snmp for network management of hosts; I have not found it as easy to get the kind of info you are asking for from it.

If you want to do a full evaluation, Nagios is another widely used package with a free option, but I have no info on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/doc-debian.html) , the list of feature can be found [here](http://www.monitorix.org/features.html).

> Monitorix is a free, open source, lightweight system monitoring tool designed to monitor as many services and system resources as possible. It has been created to be used under production Linux/UNIX servers, but due to its simplicity and small size can be used on embedded devices as well.

To install it on Ubuntu , add the following line to your [`sources.list`](http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu/dists/generic/):

```
deb http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic universe
```

Add the gpg key:

```
wget http://apt.izzysoft.de/izzysoft.asc
apt-key add izzysoft.asc
```

Install it:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install monitorix
```

Open this url: `http://localhost:8080/monitorix/` on your browser.

To get alerted through sms or mails you can use [nagios](https://www.nagios.com/solutions/linux-monitoring/)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.icinga.com/, along with deployment via Chef or Puppet. FYI, there is no "best". But Icinga is very good. You can find more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icinga).

You do need to have someone to catch the alerts and interpret the output.

Comment: Hmm... This was downvoted twice - but the other opinions were upvoted. :(